# jQuery get index of class by keydown in input field

Tags: jquery, dom

Input fields occur dynamically by what the user needs in my script.

For example:

```
<div class='row'><input class='number' type='text' /><<input class='total' type='text' /></div> 
<div class='row'><input class='number' type='text' /><<input class='total' type='text' /></div> 
<div class='row'><input class='number' type='text' /><<input class='total' type='text' /></div>
```

I want to know on keyup which input field is changed and do something with the inputted value. My idea is to do that by the class index.

I tried to get the class index by the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".number").keydown(function(){
    alert($(this).index());
    });
});
```

But which field I test, he shows index 0 instead of index 1 or two if I type something in an other input field. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without arguments `.index` returns the index of the element among its siblings. The `.number` element always seems to be the first child of its parent, so the index is always `0`.

You can either do:

```
$(this).parent().index();
```

if each of the siblings of the parent element contains a `.number` element.

Or select all `.number` elements first and get the index of the element within that set:

```
var $numbers = $('.number');
// ...
$numbers.index(this);
```